# Button icon does not render properly in iPhone X even if the DevTools displays it properly

Tags: html, css, ios, angular, mobile

I created `Scroll to top` button for my app, and when I test it in my Chrome and Safari DevTools, it displays correctly in all devices:

[image]

But, when I open it in iPhone X, the icon inside the button is not displayed correctly (even if the Chrome and Safari DevTools shows that the iPhone X would display it correctly):

[image]

Here is `HTML`:

```html
<div class="scroll-to-top" [ngClass]="{'show-scrollTop': windowScrolled}">
  <button class="scroll-to-top-button" (click)="scrollToTop()">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up scroll-to-top-arrow"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is `CSS`:

```css
.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}
.show-scrollTop {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s;
}
.scroll-to-top-button {
  background-color: #7496ee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
.scroll-to-top-button:hover {
  background-color: darken(#7496ee, 5%);
}
.scroll-to-top-arrow {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

I would also like to mention that this is an `Angular` app.

Comment: Have you inspected the element to see what styles are applied in each case?

Comment: I tried but I don't know what I am searching for here since this issue is present only when I open an app on actual phone, and not when checking it in console.

Comment: But since your application is in Angular, and therefore, probably has a webview, you can inspect it via Safari when you open your application.

Comment: I did, I checked it both in Chrome and in Safari, and tested all devices both in Chrome console and Safari console. And it displays properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by explicitly specifying that the content of the button has to be centered, (and also I removed padding from button but I guess that is not important for the fix):

```css
.scroll-to-top-button {
  background-color: #7496ee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

It is still strange that it worked on DevTools but not on the phone (It's like it was positioned on the right on the phone).